# What is a "nominal type" in the context of an inherent implementation?

Tags: rust

I am currently going through [the Rust Documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/reference/items/implementations.html#inherent-implementations) to understand inherent implementations. What is the "nominal type" and what are they referring to when then they say "associable items to the implementing type"?

Is there a related analog to this in C or C++?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, that's the language reference.  Learning Rust with that is certainly possible, but a little bit like trying to learn English by reading a dictionary.  Have you tried the [Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/)?

Anyway, as the first paragraph states, the "nominal type" is, well:

```
impl /* --> */ Point /* <-- this is the "nominal type" */ {
    fn log(&self) { ... }
}
```

It's the type which is the subject of the inherent `impl`.  An "associable item" is an item (like a `fn`, `const`, or `type`) which is associated with the nominal type.

If you had the paragraph:

> Let's talk about Raymond.  His hair is brown.  He knows how to dance.

That would be roughly equivalent to:

```
struct Raymond; // introduce the Raymond type.

impl Raymond { // associate some items with Raymond.
    const HAIR: Colour = Colour::Brown;

    fn dance(&mut self) { ... }
}

fn main() {
    let mut ray = Raymond;
    println!("Raymond's hair is {}", Raymond::HAIR);
    ray.dance();
}
```

(As an aside: the pronouns in the paragraph (like "he" or "him") would become `self` or `Self` in the `impl`.)

The `impl` is associating those items with the nominal type.  Notice how `HAIR` is "inside" of the `Raymond` type.  You could *also* write the above code as:

```
struct Raymond;

const RAYMOND_HAIR: Colour = Colour::Brown;

fn raymond_dance(ray: &mut Raymond) { ... }

fn main() {
    let mut ray = Raymond;
    println!("Raymond's hair is {}", RAYMOND_HAIR);
    raymond_dance(&mut ray);
}
```

Here, there're no inherent `impl`s, so the `RAYMOND_HAIR` and `raymond_dance` items aren't associated with the `Raymond` type directly.  There's no fundamental difference between the two, other than convenience.

As for tying this back to C++... that's tricky since Rust distinguishes between inherent and non-inherent `impl`s and C++... *doesn't*.  The closest analogue would be to say that they're like the parts of a `struct` body that aren't fields and aren't overriding methods in a base class.

Answer (score 1):

An inherent implementation is the equivalent of creating a class in a OOP language. The difference in Rust is that data is separated from implementation:

```
/* Data */
struct Foo {
    // all data there
    //...
}

/* Inherent implementation */
impl Foo {
    fn bar(&self) {
        //...
    }
}
```

- The *nominal type* is the data that you implement.
- The *associable items* are the methods that you add to the data. Those functions are special because you can call them with the syntax `foo.bar()`.

---

The *inherent implementation* is called like that as opposed to *trait implementation*:

```
/* Trait implementation */
impl Debug for Foo {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> Result<(), Error> {
        //...
    }
}
```

- In the case of inherent implementation, the method is bound to the data only. It has a sense only with *this* data.
- In the case of a trait implementation, the method can be implemented for any data that implements the trait.

---

The equivalent in C++ could be:

```cpp
struct Debug {
    virtual std::string fmt() = 0;
}

class Foo: public Debug {
    // all data there
    //...

public:
    /* Equivalent of inherent implementation */
    void bar() {
        //...
    }

    /* Equivalent of trait implementation:
       implementation of base class */
    std::string fmt() {
        //...
    }
}
```

In C++, you cannot separate "inherent implementation" from "trait implementation" (I put those between quotes, because those terms do not make sense in C++, of course).

---

Note that unlike in C++, in Rust the methods are not really different that a free function. You can call the `bar` method like this:

```
Foo::bar(foo);
```

and if you define this function:

```
fn qux(f: &Foo) {
    //...
}
```

it will have the same signature as `Foo::bar`.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this when trying to implement functions on an associated struct of a struct:

```rust
impl <$$name as SingleModelInstance>::Model where $$name: SingleModelInstance {
    fn test() {}
}
```

```bash
error[E0118]: no nominal type found for inherent implementation
   --> lib/vexflow/core/src/inheritance.rs:400:22
    |
400 |                   impl <$$name as SingleModelInstance>::Model where $$name: SingleModelInstance {
    |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ impl requires a nominal type
```

Though the error sounds obscure, it's pretty clear what it wants. The type for the impl{} block should be concretely given, nominally, with a name, and not through a formula.